# Error when building java web app outside eclipse using ANT

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a java web project on which I use ANT to perform the build. If I pull code from CVS repository *inside* the Eclipse workspace using Eclipse tooling to pull code, and then use the build.xml ANT file to perform the build, it builds succesfully and I am able to deploy to the web container and login. If I pull code from CVS repository *outside* the Eclipse workspace using a linux cvs client and then use the build.xml ANT file to perform the build, it builds succesfully and I am able to deploy to the web container, but when I try to login I am presented with  some errors stating "Could not find the required X class...". In Eclipse workspace, the files that differ from remote CVS are .*classpath* and *.factorypath*. These two files are not referenced in the build.xml and are supposed not to be used as part of ANT build. I am wondering if these two files might be the answer to why when I build/deploy from Eclipse workspace I see no errors when I login and when I do it outside Eclipse workspace I am unable to login without errors, any ideas? I am wondering also if it could be related to deployment assembly and/or bound/unbound projects.

Comment: Eclipse is probably packaging stuff automatically. See project setup (build path).

Comment: Which class isn't found? You can't be nonspecific about this sort of thing.

Comment: There are several not found classes, all of them are project specific